# Error 500: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/validation/Validator

Tags: java, bean-validation, websphere-8

i am using WebSphere version 8.5.5.1 that contains an EAR file.
I am using java bean validation,so i added all jar needed in SHARED_LIBRARY of WebSphere.but i get below error when i did some tests.

Your helps please.Thanks

```
  Error 500: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  javax/validation/Validator.forExecutables&#40;&#41;Ljavax/validation/executable 
   /ExecutableValidator&#59;
 --------------------------------
```

I am using this config in jboss-deployement-structure and works fine,what is the equivalente in webSphere?

```
    <module name="javaee.api">
        <imports>
            <exclude-set>
                <path name="javax/ws/rs" />
                <path name="javax/ws/rs/core" />
                <path name="javax/ws/rs/ext" />
                <path name="javax/validation" />
                <path name="javax/validation/bootstrap" />
                <path name="javax/validation/constraints" />
                <path name="javax/validation/groups" />
                <path name="javax/validation/metadata" />
                <path name="javax/validation/spi" />
                <path name="javax/el/**" />
            </exclude-set>
        </imports>
    </module>               
</dependencies>

<!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
<exclusions>
    <module name="asm.asm" />
    <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />
    <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
    <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
    <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
    <module name="org.slf4j" />
    <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
    <module name="org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j" />    
    <module name="javaee.api"/>
    <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
    <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
    <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
    <module name="javax.el.api" />
</exclusions>
```

Comment: you probably have a conflicting version of the bean validation (`javax.validation.*`) API in your app or shared library. It is best to exclude Java EE APIs from your application/sharedLibs and just let the WebSphere runtime provide them

Comment: Thanks @AndyGuibert for your response.Please how can exclude Java EE APIs from your application/sharedLibs??

Comment: you (the user) have full control over your application you deploy on WAS, so you can remove the libs however you like. If you build your application with Maven for example, ensure that Java EE dependencies are marked `provided` scope

Comment: @AndyGuibert i edited my request to have an idea about what i have.